# Lambda expression usage with Selenium2 ExpectedCondition?

Tags: lambda, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

After reading an article about JDK1.8 and Lambda expressions, I realized that the ExpectedCondition block that I have been using for the last few years is probably suitable to be expressed as a Lambda expression.

Given this wait object:

```
Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>( driver )
       .withTimeout(30, SECONDS)
       .pollingEvery(5, SECONDS)
       .ignoring( NoSuchElementException.class );
```

**Can anyone tell me how I can convert this ExpectedCondition expression, for Selenium, into a Lambda expression?**

```
  WebElement foo = wait.until( new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
       public WebElement apply( WebDriver webDriver ) {
           return webDriver.findElement( By.id("foo") );
       }
  } );
```

Comment: `wait.until(webDriver -> webDriver.findElement(By.id("foo")))`

Comment: That looks right to me.  Thanks for the quick answer.   I am still trying to wrap my head around that syntax.

Comment: I've added it as an answer since I figured it'd do better service to the site as an answer than a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Selenium version 3.2.0 the until() method will **only accept `Function<T,K>`** as parameter and taking in **`Predicate<T>` as a parameter is deprecated**.

The above decision is to make use of lambda expressions.

So to answer you question:

```
Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>( driver )
       .withTimeout(30, SECONDS)
       .pollingEvery(5, SECONDS)
       .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

//lamda expression:
WebElement foo = wait.until(d -> d.findElement(By.id("foo")));
```

Comment: Can you please explain this to me or give me a link to an article about this?

Comment: What is that you want to explain, lamda expressions or FluentWait?

Answer (score 2):

Basically, while [lamdas are not just anonymous classes](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/181743/56971) - they really help when you want to discuss verbs and offer more concise code in places anonymous classes had to be used in the past.

We want to tell Selinium to wait until an *action* occurs. With the old syntax we'd have to create a new anonymous implementation of the ExpectedCondition interface - with lambdas this is no longer the case.

So assuming that Selinium will support this syntax, it should be something like :

```
wait.until(webDriver -> webDriver.findElement(By.id("foo")))
```

Reducing the length of your code, and making it more readable.

More generally:

```
new Interface{
    public ReturnValue action(Type first,Type second...){
         return SomeExpression();
    }
}
```

Becomes:

```
(first,second) -> SomeExpression();
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite.  With Java 8 we should be able to replace an anonymous inner class implementing a "single abstract method interface" with a lambda as follows:

```
new FluentWait<WebDriver>( driver )   // Would be nice!
   .withTimeout(30, SECONDS)
   .pollingEvery(5, SECONDS)
   .ignoring( NoSuchElementException.class )
   .until(wd -> wd.findElements(By.id("foo")).size() == 1);
```

The problem is that this only works if the receiving method FluentWait.until only accepts ONE "single abstract method interface".  Because until accepts more than one, you would get the following compile time error:

The method until(Predicate) is ambiguous for the type 
 FluentWait